# Stack Exchange site's footer links to its own meta rather than meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, meta, stackexchange-2.0

At the bottom of the newly-created [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) stack along with its [Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/) site, there is the standard list of links to Stack Overflow properties: Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Area 51, etc.

The "meta" link in this list points to [meta.webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/), though.  It that by design?  It seems odd to have a list that contains both the top-level Stack Overflow properties along with the single site-specific Meta site.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is by design. All future Stack Exchange 2.0 network sites will have their own site-specific meta from day one, and for the rest of the life of the site.

In analogy terms, using USA politics:

- meta.stackoverflow is Washington, D.C. -- the capital of the *entire nation*
- meta.webapps is Providence, R.I.  --  the capital of a small state

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhode_Island): *Although the power of organized crime has greatly diminished in Rhode Island over the last 20 years, its residents are still stigmatized by popular perceptions of rampant graft and corruption that have haunted the state for decades[citation needed]* -- that's WebApps for you?